# Mock a exception outside the scope of class Exception with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking

****** # I want to mock an exception beyond the scope of class Exception in Python. Below is my not-functional code. Please help identifying where's wrong. ******

from mock import patch

import unittest2

class A():

```
pass
```

class B(object):

```
def a(self):
    return True  

def b(self):
    ***# This function runs without problem and created an error outside of class Exception***
    try:
        raise A()
    except Exception as ex:
        print type(ex).__name__
    except:
        print 'error outside of Exception is captured.'    

def c(self):
    # This is for test
    try:
        self.a()
    except Exception as ex:
        print type(ex).__name__
    except:
        print 'error outside of Exception is captured.'
```

class Test(unittest2)

```
def raise_error(self):
    raise A()

@patch('B.a')
def test_c(self, mock_a):
    ***# This does not function as B().b(), instead it throws an TypeError Exception. I need to mock an error not inherited from class Exception ***
    mock_a.side_effect = self.raise_error
    B().c()
```

Comment: The purpose is 'after mocking, the behavior of B.c should be exactly as B.b'

Comment: Do some research: https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. My question is, the mocking side_effect does not do what I expected. It turns an error/exception not inherited from class Exception into one does.

Comment: At least, within test_c, if I change self.raise_error into BaseException(), it works.

Comment: BaseException is mother of all exceptions! That is why it does work.